# ReactJS - Communicating change in State between Components

Tags: reactjs

**I have the following components:**

[image]

As my button component is generic, so are its events, the same holds true with my unordered list; it is the dropdown that sets the events. Here is the relevant code for both:

**Button Component:**

```
render(){
  return(

    {/* whenClicked is a dropdown property  /*}
    <button onClick={this.props.whenClicked} type="button">
    .....
    </button>
    )
```

**Unordered List Component:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        open:false
    }
}
render(){
    return(

         {/* toggle between show and hide  /*}
        <ul className={"dropdown-menu " + (this.state.open ? 'show' : '')}>
            {this.props.dropItems.map(function(item){
               ......
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Being that the button component is generic, its click event depends on dropdown component's **whenClicked** property.

**The Dropdown Component:**

```
   'use strict'; 
   var React = require('react'),
       Button = require('./button'),
       UnorderedList = require('./unordered-list');

   class Dropdown extends React.Component{

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          open:false
      }

     // added this as an update to my question per ssorallen
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
   }

   handleClick(){
      this.setState({open : !this.state.open});
   }

  render(){

      return(
          <div className="dropdown">
              {/* whenClicked is a property not an event, per se. */}
              <Button whenClicked={this.handleClick}  />
              ......
             {/* // prop.items comes from app.jsx  */}
              <UnorderedList dropItems={this.props.items} />
          </div>
      )
  } }

   module.exports = Dropdown;
```

**App.jsx:**

```
 ....
       var selectItems = {
           title : "Choose a Fruit",
           items : [
               "Cantaloupe",
                .........
        ]
    }

    <Dropdown items={selectItems.items} multiSelect={true} title={selectItems.title} />
....
```

**What's happening in this picture:**

1. App.jsx's passes fruit items to the **dropdown component**.
2. The **dropdown** in turn passes those items to the **unordered list**.
3. The button component is wired to the dropdown's whenClicked property.
4. The unorderlist component has the initial state of **open** set to **false** per to it's attribute:

   ```
     className={"dropdown-menu " + (this.state.open ? 'show' : '')}
   ```

All this works.

**My problem:**

When the button is clicked, the dropdown's whenClicked event is suppose to fire and toggle the **state of open**.

That event is suppose to trigger the unordered list to toggle it's **open state** between true & false, thus adding/removing **show** from its class "dropdown-menu".

Can someone kindly shed some light for me on how to get the dropdown component to communicate to the unordered list when the state.open is changed?

The error I am getting is:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined**

Comment: You really should accept one of the two answers if they solved your problem (which I believe they did). Personally I think ssorallens answer best answers your initial question. The guys took time to reply, you owe them that much..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. Removed the state entirely from the UnorderedList class.
2. Created toggleState prop w/state's value for UnorderedList in Dropdown,
3. Passed that property to the UnorderedList's 'dropdown-menu' class.

**UnorderedList class:**

```
 'use strict';
 var React = require('react');

 class UnorderedList extends React.Component{

     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     }
     render(){
         var listItemStyle = {
             cursor:'pointer'
         };

    return(
        <ul className={"dropdown-menu " + (this.props.toggleState ? 'show' : '')} role='menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu1'>
            {this.props.dropItems.map(function(item){
                return (<li style={listItemStyle} key={item}><a>{item}</a></li>)
            })}
        </ul>
    )
} }

  module.exports = UnorderedList;
```

**Dropdown class:**

```
  'use strict';
  var React = require('react'),
      Button = require('./button'),
      UnorderedList = require('./unordered-list');

  class Dropdown extends React.Component{

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
              open:false
          }
          this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
      }

handleClick(){
    this.setState({open : !this.state.open});
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="dropdown">
            {/* whenClicked is a property not an event, per se. */}
            <Button whenClicked={this.handleClick} className="btn-warning" title={this.props.title} subTitleClassName="caret"></Button>
            <UnorderedList dropItems={this.props.items} toggleState={this.state.open} />
        </div>
    )
  }
 }
   module.exports = Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 3):

When extending `React.Component` with ES6 classes, member methods are no longer "auto-bound" like they are when passing an object to `React.createClass`. You can [bind them in the constructor](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding) to get the behavior you're used to:

```js
class Dropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    ...
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
    </div>
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: OK, I added "this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)" to my dropdown's constructor and am no longer getting the error, but the unordered list is not changing it's open state. I do not know what that div element is you have in your example.

Comment: I do not see where your recommendations are telling my unordered list to toggle it's open state.